# What can I do with a Sunlight Threshcone?

Tags: warframe

Found a few of these objects called "Sunlight Threshcone" on the ground while adventuring in the fields outside Cetus on Earth.  The thing doesn't seem to be interactive in any way; I can't pick it up, shoot it, melee attack it, or do anything else to it that I can think of.

What is this?

[image: Sunlight Threshcone]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Sunlight Threshcone](https://warframe.fandom.com/wiki/Sunlight_Threshcone) is a scannable object that is used so far only in the Mission [The Silver Grove](https://warframe.fandom.com/wiki/The_Silver_Grove) and a few consumable types.

It is used for a few of the recipes and objectives in the The Silver Grove mission which the player is required to craft to progress, and in the recipes for [Antitoxins](https://warframe.fandom.com/wiki/Antitoxin_(Gear)) and [Apothics](https://warframe.fandom.com/wiki/Apothic).

Comment: In all the time I've spent playing Warframe (despite having some in inventory), I've never used them, and the wiki might be out of date.

Comment: The Antitoxins are pretty useless, but Apothics can be used to re-face the Spectre minibosses for some fairly rare mods (they don't drop mods at all during The Silver Grove).  Fighting the Spectres also shows up as a Nightwave weekly challenge where you have to fight 3 of them, thus needing 3 Apothics.

Comment: Iirc Antitoxins can(slightly) increase mobile defense rewards on earth forests (though not by much), a leftover from an old event.

Answer (score 0):

Threshcones are used to craft apothics used in The Silver Grove (both during the quest itself and after completing it)

That are a way to gain several Aura mods (and a couple of stances) as far as I remember.